# Vue.js components are not working in jsp files

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat, vue.js

I am writing a spring MVC application and I want to use Vue for my front end. I am trying to use the x-templates to render my components but for some reason it doesn't work and the Vue devtools are not detecting any Vue.js on the page. I managed to get Vue.js working on my index.jsp file but it doesnt work for my hotels,jsp file.

main.js:

```
let getJsonData = (url)=>{
    let result = [];
    $.getJSON(url, (data)=>{
        data.forEach((x)=>{
            result.push(x);
        });
    })
    return result;
};

Vue.component('hotel', {
    template: '#hotel-template',
    data:function(){
        return {
            msg:'Yoshi'
        }
    }
})

let app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        navLinks:[
            {
                name:'login',
                path:'/login'
            },
            {
                name:'sign up',
                path:''
            }
        ],
        countries:[],
        allHotels:getJsonData('./hotels'),

    }
})
```

header.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link  href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <div id="app">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item" v-for="link in navLinks">
                <a class="nav-link" v-bind:href="link.path">{{link.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="container">
```

footer.jsp:

```
            </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@include file = "header.jsp" %>
    <header class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                <h1 class="display-1">Bon voyage!</h1>
                <p> Dear <strong>${user}</strong>, Welcome to ${user} Page.
        <a href="./logout">Logout</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                <select id="country_select">
                    <option>Choose country</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header> <!--end of jumbotron -->
    <main>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <h4>Hotel name</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <h4>Hotel Country</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <h4>Hotel City</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <h4>Hotel address</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div v-for="hotel in allHotels" class="row">
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <a v-bind:href='"./hotel/" + hotel.id'>{{ hotel.name }}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                {{ hotel.country }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                {{ hotel.city }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                {{ hotel.address }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

<!--        <a href="./reviews">reviews</a>
        <a href="./hotel_requests">hotel requests</a>
        <a href="./hotels">hotels</a>-->
<%@include file = "footer.jsp" %>
```

hotels.jsp:

```
<%@include file = "header.jsp" %>

<script type="text/x-template" id="#hotel-template">
    <header>
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    </header>
</script>
<%@include file = "footer.jsp" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt manage to fins a solution to my problem, However I found an alternative that worked. Vue.js also has inline templates that has the same functionality as x-templates. A solution was to to put the following tag:

```
<hotel></hotel>
```

with the inline-template attribute with it. The end result would look like this

`<hotel inline-template></hotel>`

Answer (score 0):

You should load vue.js just before the  tag, not in the head area.

This will allow you to use the template: with your template in backticks (``) - that way you can have a multi-line template without having to build it as a string.